# How can I use C# to get response from Java soap1.1 service using X509 certification and encryption?

Tags: java, c#, web-services, encryption, x509certificate

We have a C# .NET 4.5 framework application that exploit soap1.1 Java web service using 3DES-CBC with RSA 1.5 padding encryption algorithm and security standard web service:

```
Wssp1.2-2007-Wss1.1-X509-Basic256.xml
Wssp1.2-2007-Wss1.1-X509-TripleDesRsa15.xml
Wssp1.2-2007-EncryptBody.xml
Wssp1.2-2007-SignBody.xml
```

These policies refer to the following Standards:

```
WS-SecurityPolicy 1.2
WS-Policy
WS-Security 1.1 X509 Token
```

I never use this security part, I have the certificate `.pfx`. Can any one help?